# How to know what class is being deserialized in JackSon Deserializer?

Tags: google-app-engine, jackson

I'm using app engine datastore so I have entity like this.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Author {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonKeySerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonKeyDeserializer.class)
    private Key key;

    ....
}
```

When the model is sent to view, it will serialize the Key object as an Id value. Then, if I send data back from view I want to deserialize the Id back to Key object by using `JsonKeyDeserializer` class.

```
public class JsonKeyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Key> {

    @Override
    public Key deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializeContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String id = jsonParser.getText();
        if (id.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        // Here is the problem because I have several entities and I can't fix the Author class in this deserializer like this. 
        // I want to know what class is being deserialized at runtime.

        // return KeyFactory.createKey(Author.class.getSimpleName(), Integer.parseInt(id))
    }
}
```

I tried to debug the value in deserialize's parameters but I can't find the way to get the target deserialized class. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have misunderstood the role of `KeySerializer`/`KeyDeserializer`: they are used for Java `Map` keys, and not as generic identifiers in database sense of term "key".
So you probably would need to use regular `JsonSerializer`/`JsonDeserializer` instead.

As to type: it is assumed that handlers are constructed for specific types, and no extra type information is passed during serialization or deserialization process: expected type (if handlers are used for different types) must be passed during construction.
When registering general serializers or deserializers, you can do this when implementing `Module`, as one of the arguments is type for which (de)serializer is requested.

When defining handlers directly for properties (like when using annotations), this information is available on `createContextual()` callback of interface `ContextualSerializer` (and -Deserializer), if your handler implements it: `BeanProperty` is passed to specify property (in this case field with annotation), and you can access its type. This information needs to be stored to be used during (de)serialization.

**EDIT**: as author pointed out, I actually misread the question: KeySerializer is the class name, not annotation.

Comment: Hi, StaxMan. Thanks for answer to my question but you may misunderstand my question about `KeyDeserializer` because I already used `JsonDeserializer` to deserialize the value. Furthermore, sorry that I didn't mention that I use Spring MVC, so I use `@RequestBody Author author` for convert JSon to Java Object. Then, after looking for `ContextualSerializer` I think that I cannot use it in this way right? Please advise me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As to whether ContextualSerializer/Deserializer works: what you could figure out is just that type `Key` is the expected static type. I am not sure if that would be enough. And since you are using annotation, registering of (de)serializers is not relevant: those are not used in this case.

Comment: One additional idea: Contextual(De)Serializer does allow you to access annotations that 'private Key key' field has, so if nothing else works, you could actually use custom annotations to pass information that you need. Only caveat is that your annotations need to use `@JacksonAnnotation` to be passed along (in 1.9 at least, this restriction will be removed in 2.0).

Comment: Implement my own Annotations solves the problem. Haven't thought of this before. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: That is understandable: there isn't much documentation on how to do this, but it is a very powerful and flexible method -- possible only with Jackson 1.8 and above. Hope it works out!